# What is the time complexity of a while (true) loop?

Tags: time, complexity-theory

I'm working on the minimum vertex cover problem using Genetic algorithm.

To create the initial population, its initial solutions must cover the graph G(V,E) under process. To create an initial solution, it is represented as binary vector with length equals to the number of graph vertices (V). The value of each vertex in this vector will be 1 if a generated random number > 0.01, or 0 otherwise.

The following is a piece of my code:

```
while (population size != n)//n: number of initial population solutions 
    while(true)
    {
       create initial solution S // as described in advance which it is O(V)
       if (S cover graph G) then // checking solution coverage is O(E), E: number of edges
       {
          add S to the initial population
          increase population size by 1
          exit while loop 
        }
    }
```

My question is: What is its time complexity? specifically, average case! Knowing that we don't have any idea about the solution properties which can cover the graph G except that the solution vector, which all vertices values are 1, is 100% cover the graph.

Comment: Seems like this question are better asked and the math [home](https://math.stackexchange.com/) ... ( : Anyway.. if you got it solved.. don't forget to share the answer here/delete this Q. all the best

Comment: I vote to close the question as too broad. There is no unique answer as the solution depends on the chosen [random graph model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_graph). And you want the solution parameterized by the number `n`, while it makes more sense to me to choose `n` depending on the characteristics of graphs under consideration. Before asking a question of such a wide scope I would have done at least some experiments to get a feeling of possible answers.

Comment: I don't use random graph model, I'm using some of DIMACS benchmark instances where their number of vertices (V), number of edges (E), and best known solutions are identified. Besides, I have done a lot of search for the complexity of a loop with unpredictable stop condition, but I could not get any useful answer!!!

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by DIMACS benchmarks? To my knowledge there was no DIMACS Challenge for Minimial Vertex Cover (see [list](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/archive/Challenges/)). Did you mean to say that the benchmarks that you use are in DIMACS format? If they are available online, please post a link.

Comment: Thanks for your response Dmitri Chubarov ... I mean I'm using some instances (graphs) of DIMACS benchmarks for minimum vertex cover which it can also be used for clique and maximum independent set .. the following is a link for some of them ... https://turing.cs.hbg.psu.edu/txn131/vertex_cover.html#vertex_cover